# How to use JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS function in QueryBuilder with Symfony?

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine, jsonb

I try to use functions provided by https://github.com/martin-georgiev/postgresql-for-doctrine/ but Symfony returns this error :

> Error: Class 'JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS' is not defined.

Here is the code of my function in the repository file:

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
              ->from('JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(CAST(p.wp_syncs AS JSONB))', 'pwps')
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
```

The function is activated in **doctrine.yaml**:

```
dql:
    string_functions:
        # ...
        JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS: MartinGeorgiev\Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\JsonbArrayElements
```

Answer (score 2):

You can’t set a function or a subquery in the FROM clause of a Doctrine DQL query.

You should write a SQL query instead:

```php
$connection = $entityManager->getConnection(); // Get the DBAL connection

// Create a DBAL Query builder.
// Note that this query builder is NOT the same of the query builder returned by the EntityManager.
$qb = $connection->createQueryBuilder();

$qb->select('*')
    ->from('jsonb_array_elements(CAST(p.wp_syncs AS JSONB))', 'pwps')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

In this case you don’t need to register the function in doctrine’s configuration.

Comment: I can't see the difference between your code and mine… Do I need to write a a raw SQL query instead?

Comment: The query builder created by the connection is not the same returned by the entity manager: the first one builds a SQL query, the other builds a DQL query, which does not support functions and subqueries in the FROM clause. I've edited my answer to make it clearer.